# Trying to work together with groupby and Anova

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anova

I have a data set with categorical values for Family size (1 to 4) and Loan taken (0 and 1). I want to know if there is significant diff between the mean of family size and loan taken. 
I did groupby to get the count of Loan by family size  as :

```
gp = df.groupby(["Family", "Personal Loan"])["Personal Loan"].count()
```

with output

```
Family  Personal Loan
1       0                1365
        1                 107
2       0                1190
        1                 106
3       0                 877
        1                 133
4       0                1088
        1                 134
```

Now I need to apply f_two way anova to see if there is significant difference between the loan taken and family size. Need help how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do an two way anova with count data and binary response. What you can do is a chisq test, to test that the proportions of loan==1 are not equal across all families:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
```

I have to get back something like your original df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Family':np.repeat(np.arange(1,5),[1472,1296,1010,1222]),
    'Personal Loan':np.repeat([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [1365,107,1190,106,877,133,1088,134]),
})
gp = df.groupby(["Family","Personal Loan"])["Personal Loan"].count()
gp

Family  Personal Loan
1       0                1365
        1                 107
2       0                1190
        1                 106
3       0                 877
        1                 133
4       0                1088
        1                 134
Name: Personal Loan, dtype: int64
```

Now we do the chi-sq using crosstab:

```
contingency = pd.crosstab(df['Family'],df['Personal Loan'])
test = chi2_contingency(contingency)
test

(29.676116414854746, 1.6144121228248757e-06, 3, array([[1330.688,  141.312],
        [1171.584,  124.416],
        [ 913.04 ,   96.96 ],
        [1104.688,  117.312]]))
```

The 2nd value, 1.614e-06 is the p-value of your test that all the loan == 1 ratios are equal